# Expose method from Svelte web component

Tags: javascript, web-component, svelte

I'd like to have a method exposed from a Svelte web component so that consumers of the component may call it.

Say I have a simple Svelte web component here:

```
<script>
    export function someMethod() {
      console.log("I was called");
    }
</script>

<svelte:options tag="svelte-div" />

<style>
    div {
      background: #ff3e00;
    }
</style>

<div>
  I am just a placeholder
</div>
```

And some agnostic consumer should be able to call that method. Could be Svelte, could be vanilla, could be React. Like this:

```
  const svelteDiv = document.querySelector("svelte-div");
  if (svelteDiv) svelteDiv.someMethod();
```

Svelte's `compilerOptions: true` is set.

The above works flawlessly in stencilJS and I thought this must be possible with Svelte, too. The build files on my machine also include the necessary `customElements.define` lines and yet I can't call this method on the DOM node. I can't find anything in the docs. Below is a sandbox of the setup above.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-euler-jp9ejd?file=/App.svelte

Comment: You cannot change build settings, see comment at the top of the rollup config. Also your code does not contain a `<svelte-div>` tag anywhere in the HTML, so this will not work even if built correctly (`querySelector` only finds existing elements).

Answer (score 1):

You try to create and to use the custom element from the same project, which I don't think can work. If you add the compiler option `customElement: true`, a `bundle.js` file will be created under `public/build` when building the project with `npm run build`. This file contains the custom elements and can then be copied, renamed and used in a different project.

Like mentioned in the comments it looks like you can't change the `rollup.config` file in the codesandbox. Besides you need access to the terminal to run the build. In the codesandbox docs two environments are mentioned [Client & Container Environments](https://codesandbox.io/docs/environment) The Svelte one seems to be a Client environment without a terminal. Maybe everything could be set up via a Container Environment, but I assume it would be better to switch to a locally installed IDE like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Here's a [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-web-components-svelte/) going trough the process of building web components.

There are basicily three steps

- add `<svelte:options tag="my-custom-element" />` to top of Component you want to export
- add `customElement: true` to compiler options in `rollup.config.js`
- adjust `main.js` so that it contains only imports of the components you want to export as web components like `import MyCustomElement from './MyCustomElement.svelte';` and nothing else

The exported function can be called on the custom element and unlike with Svelte Components

> By default, custom elements are compiled with accessors: true, which means that **any props are exposed as properties of the DOM element** (as well as being readable/writable as attributes, where possible).